# Is it possible to generate an Excel VBA Listview - on a 64bit machine?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been scouring the internet all afternoon trying to see why I can't get an Excel VBA form that works on my 32bit Excel 2003 to work on Excel 2010 which is 64bit.

From what I'm finding, IT CAN'T WORK.  Is this really correct?

If so, are there any alternatives to use for listview in Excel 64bit?

Comment: Might offer some alternative: [*An MSForms (all VBA) treeview* & **Pro ListGrid**](https://jkp-ads.com/articles/treeview.asp); note that the pro versions are paid versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct. See [this article at microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility), specifically:

> Native 64-bit processes in Office 2010 cannot load 32-bit binaries. This includes the common controls of **MSComCtl** (TabStrip, Toolbar, StatusBar, ProgressBar, TreeView, ListViews, ImageList, Slider, ImageComboBox) and the controls of **MSComCt2** (Animation, UpDown, MonthView, DateTimePicker, FlatScrollBar).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in Molot's answer, it is not possible to use the 32-bit common controls in 64-bit Office 2010.

However, for higher* versions of 64-bit Office, you can install and register [MSCOMCTL.OCX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=10019) for use inside VBA. [This article](https://www.urtech.ca/2017/11/solved-mscomctl-ocx-download-register-64-bit-windows/) might also be helpful, but I'd suggest to use the official Microsoft page for the download.

Basically, what you'll have to do on a 64-bit version of Windows, is go to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and register the `.ocx` file with the following command (Cmd or Powershell) running as Administrator:

```
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
```

Note that the Microsoft download page gives you a `.exe` which is supposed to make the update, but it won't install the file if it is not present. If you are in that situation, you can always extract the `.ocx` from the `.exe` provided by Microsoft using an archive extractor like 7zip ([instructions](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/extract-msi-from-exe.html#:%7E:text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20the%20EXE,and%20choosing%20the%20extract%20option.)).

Once, you've registered mscomctl.ocx, you should see it available in the list of references in VBA:

[image]

Then, inside a form you can add the ListView control:

[image]

[image]

---

* : It works on my version of 64-bit Office 365 (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16721.20000) 64-bit), but I can't confirm if it will work for Office 2019 or 2021. Some people have confirmed that it doesn't work on Office 2016 however ([more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/860672/vba-excel-2016-msi-64-bit-problem-with-listview-el?source=docs)).

Comment: If you read information at the very links you have posted, you will see that the first one features the (very old) VB6 common controls (as opposed to VBA) and does not mention 64-bit in any way, and the second one instructs how to correctly install 32-bit common controls on a 64-bit Windows. There are no 64-bit controls.

Comment: @GSerg I wrote 64-bit compatible in the sense that they are compatible with the 64-bit version of Office 365, not that it is a 64-bit binary. I've edited my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: They are not compatible with 64-bit versions of anything. By installing them [in C:\Windows\SysWOW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) you are only making them available for 32-bit Office. If you have an Office installation that can use them, you have a 32-bit Office installation.

Comment: @GSerg Based on this [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-2017#office-suite-non-security-updates-7) from Microsoft in 2017, it seems that they managed to make it work. My understanding is that running `regsvr32` is what makes it possible. From Office's perspective there is a file with the name `mscomctl.ocx` in System32, but when I look inside System32 in file explorer, that file doesn't exist. So, there must be  some shenanigans going on in the background.

Comment: Obviously, there's more to it than just `regsvr32` because they've had to customize the way Office behaves. I think the discussion on how it works is interesting, but it remains that it works.

Comment: If a 64-bit version was indeed developed, it must have not been put into SysWOW64. Only 32-bit versions go there. I guess a possibility remains that they turned it into an [out-of-process COM server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68278915/11683) that runs 32-bit and marshals the calls for 64-bit clients.